# How to cause an action on a button when you press a different button?

Tags: python, kivy, instance, kivy-language, chess

So this is a game where I have some starter code in kivy. Here is some of it:

```
GridLayout:
    id: chess_board
    cols: 8
    rows: 8
    padding: ("60dp", "60dp", "60dp", "60dp")
    orientation: 'lr-bt'
    
    Button:
        id: button_1
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_1
            source: 'imgs/WhiteCastle.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_2
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_2
            source: 'imgs/WhiteKnight.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_3
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_3
            source: 'imgs/WhiteBishop.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_4
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)
        AsyncImage:
            id: white_4
            source: 'imgs/WhiteQueen.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
        

    Button:
        id: button_5
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_5
            source: 'imgs/WhiteKing.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
        
    Button:
        id: button_6
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_6
            source: 'imgs/WhiteBishop.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
        
    Button:
        id: button_7
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_7
            source: 'imgs/WhiteKnight.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_8
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_8
            source: 'imgs/WhiteCastle.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y  #8
        
    Button:
        id: button_9
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_9
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_10
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_10
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_11
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_11
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
    
    Button:
        id: button_12
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press:root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_12
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_13
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)
        AsyncImage:
            id: white_13
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
    
    Button:
        id: button_14
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_14
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_15
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_15
            source: 'imgs/WhitePawn.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
    
    Button:
        id: button_16
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)
```

So whenever I press a button that contains an image i.e a chess piece I want to show what moves the users can do and want to bound the movement of the piece to only those moves but I am not sure how to perform an action on another button from one button. Here is what I have been able to come up with so far in my .py file:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def img_list(self):
    img_ids_list = []

    for x in range(1, 17):
        img_ids_list.append(f"white_{x}")

    for y in range(1, 17):
        img_ids_list.append(f"black_{y}")

    return img_ids_list

def moves(self, instance, root):
    all_ids = root.ids
    id_of_button = self.get_id(instance)
    img_id = self.check_if_img_exists(instance)

def what_moves(self, instance, root):
    if (
        root.ids.white_1 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_8 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_1 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_8 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

    if (
        root.ids.white_2 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_7 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_2 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_7 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

    if (
        root.ids.white_3 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_6 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_3 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_6 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

    if (
        root.ids.white_4 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_5 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

    if (
        root.ids.white_4 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_5 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

    if (
        root.ids.white_9 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_10 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_11 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_12 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_13 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_14 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_15 in instance.children
        or root.ids.white_16 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_9 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_10 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_11 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_12 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_13 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_14 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_15 in instance.children
        or root.ids.black_16 in instance.children
    ):
        pass

def check_if_img_exists(self, instance):
    img_ids = self.img_list()

    for x in range(0, 32):
        asyncImage = self.ids[img_ids[x]]
        if asyncImage in instance.children:
            print("Button contains an AsyncImage")
            return asyncImage
    print("Button does not contain an AsyncImage")

def get_id(self, instance):
    for id, widget in instance.parent.parent.ids.items():
        if widget.__self__ == instance:
            return id
```

Comment: every button has ID and you can use it to access buttons. And if you have to do something on many buttons then maybe use `for`-loop

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to keep information in normal list `8x8` and make all calculations on tthis list - and later use this information to display on Buttons.

Comment: Tysm for the help I'll try that